# Bootstrap 4: auto-suggest drop-down as in the official bootstrap site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

If you go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/, you see a auto-suggest dropdown on the left site of the official boostrap site. How do I implement the same thing on my own web pages? What library is the site using for the auto suggest? I have traced the source code but I can't find the relevant code.

[image]